# TypeError while using scipy.integrate.quadrature

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I am trying to integrate the `Integrand` function which includes an interpolation. Using `scipy.integrate.quadrature` I run into this error: `TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'`. I don't run into this error when I use `scipy.integrate.quad`. I think the problem is with `thing[i]` which is an **'ndInterp' object**. Is there any way to solve this problem?

```
def Integrand(x, a, i):
   
    pnt = np.array((a, x)).reshape((1, 2))
    return thing[i].eval(pnt)

logpost = scipy.integrate.quadrature(lambda x: Integrand(x, a, i), lower_m, upper_m)[0]
```

Comment: Show the full error traceback.  And if you want us to test it, make sure all necessary variables are defined.

Comment: What does `lambda x: Integrand(x, a, i)(lower_m)` produce?  It must produce a float, or something that easily converts to such.  I'm surprised that `quad` works, since it should have the same expectation.